# Filter a dictionary if value of a key is true

Tags: python, dictionary

I am totally new to Python (day 1). I have a dataset that indicates whether someone is a person of interest via a boolean 'poi' key. I was able to filter the data with the following:

```
filtered = []
for n in enron_data:
    if enron_data[n]['poi']: filtered.append(enron_data[n]);
print(len(filtered))
```

I tried for a while to use pythons built in filter but was unable to. what is a clean way to do this with the builtin filter?

example data: `{'METTS MARK': {... 'poi': False,}, ...}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to iterate over the dictionary to then create a new list of the values that evaluate `True` for `value['poi']`.

```
filtered = [v for k, v in enron_data.items() if v['poi']]
```

In fact, you're not using the keys at all, so you could just do:

```
filtered = [v for v in enron_data.values() if v['poi']]
```

Or to use filter (similar to @AbidHasan):

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: x['poi'], enron_data.values())
```

Comment: thank you! is there any reason this is preferred over using a lambda with `.filter`? I'm coming from the JS world so that was my first instinct.

Comment: I find list comprehension easier to read than `filter` and choosing to make something more readable is usually a better choice.

Answer (score 4):

Another `filter` function

```
new_list = filter(your_dict.get, your_dict)
```

Less expensive than using `lambda` inside the `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `filter` function.

```
new_list = filter(lambda x: a[x]['POI'], a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1:11, 2:22, 3:33}

# filter by value
d3 = {}

for key,value in d.items():
    if value in [22,33]:
        d3.update({key:value})
print(d3)
```